# Firebase storage images random order in collection view

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my firebase database i have several items that have a name and an image each. In my app I would like to display said parameters in a collectionview with an imageview and a label in each cell. I'm able to display each items name in the label, and I'm also able to display the items image in the imageview, however the images downloaded from firebase keep appearing in a random order every time. The labels show the item names in a correct fixed order every time. Each item has a child named "image" with a child named "storage" which stores the image url from firebase storage. The code for downloading images:

```
func downloadImg() {
    let ref = Database.database().reference().child(itemNumber1)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        for item in snapshot.children {
            let snap = item as! DataSnapshot
            let imageSnap = snap.childSnapshot(forPath: "image/storage")
            if let url = imageSnap.value as? String {
            let someRef = self.storageRef.reference(forURL: url)
                someRef.getData(maxSize: 10 * 10024 * 10024) { data, error in
                    if let error = error {
                        print(error)
                    } else {
                        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        self.imageArray.append(image!)
                        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As I said, the code works fine, but I'd like the images to show up in the same order everytime, and the same order as they are stored in the storage/database. I tried appending the url constant to an empty array and printing it, and this array prints the storage urls in the order I want. However something seems to happen when the images themselves are appended to the imageArray.

Comment: Cloud Storage doesn't impose any kind of ordering at all on the objects stored it in.  If you see an ordering in the console, that's just the way the console has chosen to sort them (probably alphabetically).  If you want to impose your own ordering, you should do that in a database using some field value that dictates the sort order.

Comment: Is it not sufficient storing each image url as a child of each item? Since the items themselves appear ordered, and I'm able to retrieve the image url's ordered like I want I thought that would be enough.

Comment: As I said, *there is no actual ordering in Storage*.  There just appears to be order in the console, because that's how the console works.  If you want a specific order in your code, you should use a database to order the items as you want. This has nothing to do with storing download URLs, which is definitely OK.  But the order you want them to appear on screen should be determined by your code.

Comment: Would you mind explaining how one would do that? The only way of retrieving images from storage is by storing them in the database and directly downloading each image, so I have not tried anything else yet.

Comment: Firstly, build your array `imageArray` not by the order in which the files are finished downloading, but the order by which they appear in the database query.

Comment: And how do I do that? Sorry I'm quite new to coding.